# Alamofire gives an error on this

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to get my appversion from appstore using below

```
func checkfornewVersionofApp () {

    let appId = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleIdentifier"]
    let appIdString = appId as! String

    let theitunesUrl  = "http://itunes.apple.com/en/lookup?bundleId=" + appIdString           

    Alamofire.request(.GET, theitunesUrl, parameters: nil).responseJSON { response in    
        switch response.result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                print("success with json : \(JSON)") 
                break
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("some error occured : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                break
        }
    }
}
```

it always goes to `error` and gives the following

> The operation couldn’t be completed. JSON could not be serialized.
>   Input data was nil or zero length

what is the reason.hope yur help.

Comment: Try using `responseData` instead of `responseJSON`

Comment: Try using response.result.value,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the problem with your URL. Check this link [Link for iTunes API](http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.yelp.yelpiphone)

Change your code

`let theitunesUrl  = "http://itunes.apple.com/en/lookup?bundleId=" + appIdString`

to

`let theitunesUrl  = "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=" + appIdString`

In addition, you can add the country parameter to the query, to get results for a specific country App Store.

For example:

> http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.yelp.yelpiphone&country=de

The description, user rating and other fields might change between different App Store countries.

Comment: thanx mate, you did a great job